# npm throws "no such file or directory" error only when using "npm run" from another directory

Tags: npm, npm-run

Take the path

```
/a/b/c/package.json
/a/b/c/package-lock.json
```

From `/`, this works without error:

```
cd /a/b/c && npm install
```

However, from `/`, this throws an error:

```
cd /a/b/c && npm run build
```

With the error being:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

What's extra odd is that `npm run build` then proceeds to complete successfully. The error is only thrown while npm is looking up the `build` script. However, this is enough to trick my CI/CD pipeline into thinking the whole command has failed.

How can I execute `npm run ***` from another directory without this initial error?